# Solr dismax query only for boosting result

Tags: solr, solrnet

I want to use dismax query ONLY in order to boost those documents with higher score and not to execute any query. So, for example if I want to do dismax query I will set the following parameters:

```
q=my search term
qf=Field1^100 Field2^10 Field3^1
q.alt=*:*
defType:dismax
```

Now, my question is how can I still apply this setting in order to boost the result documents?
I hope I could explain the problem properly.

thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't do any query then there is nothing to boost.

A dismax query is nothing more than a query which matches in any one of several fields. You can boost a dismax query in the way that you specified, but you need to do the query to boost it.

q.alt is only used when no query is specified.